# Indentation in floating minipages

Tags: floats, indentation, minipage, multicol

I'm writing a two-column document, and I want to add some floating text boxes. I can do this with `minipage` environments nested in a `figure*` environment. However, this breaks indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{framed}
      \begin{center}
        \Large \textbf{Callout Title}
      \end{center}

      \begin{multicols}{2}
        One paragraph of text in the callout.

        \indent A second paragraph of text in the callout. This should be indented!

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \end{multicols}

    \end{framed}

\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent \blindtext

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Whether or not I include the `\indent` command, the second paragraph in my textbox remains flush, not indented:

[image]

How do I get normal paragraph indentation in floated minipages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

latex runs `\@arrayparboxrestore` in floats (and minipages and parboxes and array p columns) this resets several things including indentation:

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
```

So you might want

```
\setlength\parindent{15pt}\fussy
```

at the start of your text box, to reset the indentation and normal (fussy) white space control.

Comment: This increase column separation and consequently move image out of frame. Or I miss something?

Comment: @Zarko it doesn't affect column separation, it does however cause things in the column to be shifted by 15pt if they start a paragraph, which was the request.

Comment: I see. The picture is directly in text, so it is handled as first line of paragraph ... I miss this point.